Where is the traffic actually going with the stream from a GenerateWebRtcStream call? Am I getting local access to a device?
I'm trying to decide if it's even worth it to give google my $5 to get access to the "Device Access" API and Console etc. I want to be able to access the video streams on a Nest doorbell and a couple of nest cameras. This access will be from the same local network those devices are connected to. When I use the device access API and such to get those video streams what the hell actually happens?
Will it return a stream directly from these devices on my local network after doing their authentication magic? Is all the data first going upstream to google's servers somewhere and then coming back down to my apps? Does any of this work during an internet outage? Does it only need to authenticate once and then work locally?
None of the API docs I found seem to answer these questions using either english or any kind of technical language I am familiar with. Has anyone managed to use this API to get a video stream out of a nest camera without it all going to and from a "cloud" of some kind?
I tried reading Google's documentation, but it is not very good .

Device Access APIs are web APIs. Hence, throughout numerous steps (authentication, re-authentication , SDP Exchange , etc..) an internet connection will be needed.
In every camera WebRTC call a connectivity check might need to be done, hence these APIs will not work on a local only network.
